# Get the count of first 3 quarters record count and compare with 4th quarter record count in sql

Tags: mysql

In my table i  have amount,transactionDate columns. From the date column , i have fetched the quarter number and for each quarter i have writteen the query to get the  count of records of each quarter .

### Query :

```
select sum(amount),
    quarter(transactionDate)
from sales
group by quarter(transactionDate)
order by quarter(transactionDate) limit 10;
```

Now i would like to get the count of records of first 3 quarters and compare with the count of records of 4th quarter.And if count of records of Q4 is > 80% of count of records in Q3 then it should display the final value as "HighSales"

Please help me on this query

Comment: MySQL or Oracle?.... you tagged both

Comment: it would be great if you can tell me the query in MySql

Comment: sorry for tagging oracle database. Please share me the query in mysql

Comment: can any one please share me the query for the above requirement. this is urgent requirement. so requesting to assist me on this